# Res.redirect with cookies from google-login on windows

Tags: express, google-chrome, nestjs, google-signin

Here's the issue:
I have a website, I'm trying to log in with google, on windows. The process is :

1. From the original websiter: redirect to google + authenticate there.
2. Google posts back to the server- and we create cookies and set them,
3. The response from the above request is redirect back to the original website.

On Mac/Ubuntu, everything works just fine, and on windows- the cookies are not set. (using Chrome). Any clue?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this an [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) flow?

Comment: Yes, but the authentication request redirects to google, and google send the token to our server. I'll attach a video soon

Comment: https://www.loom.com/share/d510460978ea434f80b9062e8d8af225   this is the video to the working version - on ubuntu. Windows is not working
this is the windows video:  https://www.loom.com/share/25e8e62343b643c58dbbbcc1cc720866
And you can see that cookeis are missing. (I know the filter is on, I'm missing a cookie called `klo` )